# SQLAlchemy update if unique key exists

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, declarative

I've got a class:

```
class Tag(Base, TimestampMixin):
    """Tags"""
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    __table_args__ = {'mysql_engine' : 'InnoDB', 'mysql_charset' : 'utf8' }

    id = Column(Integer(11), autoincrement = True, primary_key = True)
    tag = Column(String(32), nullable = False, unique = True)
    cnt = Column(Integer(11), index = True, nullable = False, default = 1)

    def __init__(self, tag):
        t = session.query(Tag).filter_by(tag=tag).first()
        if t:
            self.cnt = t.cnt+1
            self.tag = t.tag
        else:
            self.tag = tag

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Tag('%s')>" % (self.tag, )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.tag, )
```

When adding tag:

```
tag = Tag('tag')
session.add(tag)
session.commit()
```

I want it to update existing `tag`.

Of course, I could've done this:

```
tag = session.query(Tag).filter_by(tag='tag').first()
if tag:
    tag.cnt++
else:
    tag = Tag('tag')
session.add(tag)
session.commit()
```

but, keeping such logic in `Tag` class seems to be more clear - possibly keeps me off of the shotgun surgery.

How do I get there?
I'm pretty new to `Python` and `SQLAlchemy`, so any additional thoughts on my code will be appreciated.

Comment: try session.merge(tag) instead of session.add(tag)

Comment: +100 on the P.S.

Comment: `session.merge` is useless here because it looks for the primary key only and not for other `unique` columns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

```
def get_or_increase_tag(tag_name):
    tag = session.query(Tag).filter_by(tag=tag_name).first()
    if not tag:
       tag = Tag(tag_name)
    else:
       tag.cnt += 1
    return tag
```

You can check the link https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Insert+on+duplicate+update+sqlalchemy

Comment: There should be a create_or_update function django orm style

Comment: But SQLAlchemy is not a Django-style ORM. It aims at letting you express your queries in Python and then let the database do its work. "create_or_update" can mean a lot of different things and SQLAlchemy doesn’t want to choose for you.

Answer (score 19):

From version *1.2* SQLAlchemy will support [`on_duplicate_key_update`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=duplicate#sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.dml.Insert.on_duplicate_key_update) for **MySQL**

There is also [examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html?highlight=duplicate#insert-on-duplicate-key-update-upsert) of how to use it:

> ```
> from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert
>
> insert_stmt = insert(my_table).values(
>     id='some_existing_id',
>     data='inserted value')
>
> on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
>     data=insert_stmt.values.data,
>     status='U'
> )
>
> conn.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
> ```

---

From version *1.1* SQLAlchemy support [`on_conflict_do_update`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=conflict#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_update) for **PostgreSQL**

[Examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=conflict#insert-on-conflict-upsert):

> ```
> from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
>
> insert_stmt = insert(my_table).values(
>     id='some_existing_id',
>     data='inserted value')
>
> do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
>     constraint='pk_my_table',
>     set_=dict(data='updated value')
> )
>
> conn.execute(do_update_stmt)
> ```

Comment: typo: `data=insert_stmt.values.data` instead `data=insert_stmt.inserted.data`

Comment: How can you do this with session?

Comment: @Ken have you managed to perform this with session?
I've an object and need to upsert it

Comment: @ArfathYahiya Was a while ago so don't quite remember but I added an answer with how I solved my issue below if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it with session:

```
def add_listing(row):
    """
    Add new listing to db if it doesn't exist, update it if it does
    """
    try:
        # Check if primary key exists already in table
        c_mlnum = row["ML #"]
        listing = db_session.query(Listings).filter(Listings.MLNum == c_mlnum)
        dup_listing = listing.first()
        if dup_listing:
            listing.update(
                {
                    v: row[k]
                    for k, v in listing_headers.items()
                    if k in row.index and not isnan(row[k]) and k != "ML #"
                }
            )
        else:
            record = Listings(
                **{
                    v: row[k]
                    for k, v in listing_headers.items()
                    if k in row.index and not isnan(row[k])
                }
            )
            db_session.add(record)  # Add current row
        db_session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        # Rollback and print error
        db_session.rollback()
        print(e)
```